# How do I slice and mask parts of a 3D array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, jupyter, slice

I am splitting up this 3D time series into just a small area using ma.masked_where, where the data is masked.
However, it is for a 3D array, rather than just a 2D.
How would I apply the same analysis (splitting and masking parts of the data) to the entire 3D array, rather than to just one time step:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import ma

 # 3d data array
data = np.random.rand(5,45,60)

# taking only the 3rd time stamp (as an example) -- now 2d array
data1 = data[2,0:30,0:30]

x2, y2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, 30, 1), np.arange(0, 30, 1))

data1 = ma.masked_where(x2 + y2 > 30, data1)
data2 = ma.masked_where(x2 + y2 < 10 , data1) #+
data3 = ma.masked_where(x2 + y2 > 25 , data2) #+
data4 = ma.masked_where(x2 - y2 > 10 , data3)
data5 = ma.masked_where(x2 - y2 < -5 , data4)

plt.contourf(data[2])
plt.xlim(0,60)
plt.ylim(0,45)
plt.show()

plt.contourf(data5)
plt.xlim(0,60)
plt.ylim(0,45)
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
# attempt at applying one part of the data mask to the 3d data array 
data1 = []


for i in range(5):
    data1.append(ma.masked_where(x2 + y2 > 30, data[i]))

data1 = np.array(data1)
```

I also tried this... which got a big closer but the mask is not copying to the original array (now renamed d):

```
d = np.random.rand(5,30,30)

mask = ma.array(data5)

print(mask.shape)
plt.contourf(mask)
plt.show()

#m = np.ma.masked_invalid(mask)
#print(m)

#test = ma.masked_where(np.ma.getmaskarray(mask),d)

x = []

for i in range(5):
        x.append(ma.masked_where(np.ma.getmaskarray(mask),d[i,:,:]))
x = np.array(x)

plt.contourf(x[2])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is by broadcasting `x2` and `y2` to the shape `(5, 30, 30)`. This allows them to be used in `ma.masked_where` with a 3D part of data:

```
data1 = data[:, 0:30, 0:30]

x2, y2 = [np.broadcast_to(a, (5, 30, 30)) for a in np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, 30, 1), np.arange(0, 30, 1))]
```

The rest of the code can remain unchanged, apart from the plotting. The entire code is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import ma

# 3d data array
data = np.random.rand(5, 45, 60)

# now taking all time stamps -- now 3d array
data1 = data[:, 0:30, 0:30]

x2, y2 = [np.broadcast_to(a, (5, 30, 30)) for a in np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, 30, 1), np.arange(0, 30, 1))]



data1 = ma.masked_where(x2 + y2 > 30, data1)
data2 = ma.masked_where(x2 + y2 < 10, data1)  # +
data3 = ma.masked_where(x2 + y2 > 25, data2)  # +
data4 = ma.masked_where(x2 - y2 > 10, data3)
data5 = ma.masked_where(x2 - y2 < -5, data4)

plt.contourf(data[2])
plt.xlim(0, 60)
plt.ylim(0, 45)
plt.show()

for data5_i in data5:
    plt.contourf(data5_i)
    plt.xlim(0, 60)
    plt.ylim(0, 45)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you! i am getting an error saying that the input z must be 2D and not 1d...

Comment: What line is this error? I am not getting this.